# html-pdf in meteor EPIPE error

Tags: node.js, pdf, meteor, npm, phantomjs

I have a Meteor app that renders a PDF server-side using `html-pdf`. The app is deployed with `mup`. Locally, everything works fine. Upon deployment, I see this error in the server logs:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:721:19)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Script restart attempt #1
```

Versions of stuff:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Meteor 1.0.4.2
- Node.js 0.10.37
- mup 0.9.7

Answer (score 8):

## Summary

The fix: `sudo apt-get install libfontconfig`

## Details

I noticed that `html-pdf` depends on and installs `phantomjs` itself. I found a couple of compiled `phantomjs` binaries:

```
/opt/testapp/app/programs/server/npm/testpackage/node_modules/html-pdf/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
/opt/testapp/app/programs/server/npm/testpackage/node_modules/html-pdf/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
```

When I tried to run either binary directly, I got this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

A web search turned up this [secret dependency](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10904).

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs also in Ubuntu v18.04.5

After install the below command it was working fine for me.

```sh
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig
```